# Does CMake compile everything in the included headers into the executable or only the parts used in the main class?

Tags: c, executable, compiler-optimization, filesize

I'm writing a C program where every bit of the executable size matters.

If, for example, only printf() from stdlib.h is required in my program, would including the header actually cause everything in that library to be copied into the CMake compiled executable?

Comment: No, but all the declarations would be available.

Answer (score 2):

CMake is just the build system generator. What ultimately goes into the final executable is decided by the linker and which options you use with it. Typical linkers will only link into the executable what they can determine to be necessary – unless you ask them to link everything. However there's some limits on how much they can reduce the footprint.

The rule of thumb is, that if you use a function found in foo.o, then the whole lot of foo.o gets linked; hence if size optimization is your goal, it's a good idea to give each function its own compilation unit.

What headers you use has no effect whatsoever, because headers are processed at compilation time, not linkage time.

Last but not least: In most implementation of the standard library, the printf family of functions is among the most heavyweight ones, so don't use them if you're beancounting.

Answer (score 0):

As a principle, headers should be *idempotent*, that is, they should not affect the executable if the declarations are not used.  `stdlib.h` should only have things like prototypes, pre-processor macro definitions and struct definitions, it should not contain executable code or variable declarations.

Standard library *code* is included by the linker as required.  However, the C runtime-library library (RTL) might have this code in a DLL or shared object, depending on your platform.  Using a DLL (or equivalent) does not affect the size of the executable file, but of course can affect the memory used.  Since DLL code is shared between processes it is not uncommon for the C RTL to remain in memory, but, assuming dynamic linking, there will only be one copy, regardless of the number of C processes running.  Most C RTLs will have some memory allocated per-process, but how much depends on the compiler/platform.